# Is it possible to get a rough timeline/cost estimate for the future monero development?

Tags: development, implementation

I know that this question is a bit of a stretch, so it might be good to go with this overview from the official Monero homepage (https://getmonero.org/design-goals/)

To be more specific, which of the listed items are already in development? Which of the items can be patched with a rough cost/time estimate?

I do realize that there is no definitive answer to my question.

Comment: I really think this question is too general. It would be better if you asked about a specific item on the roadmap instead of all of them.

Comment: You could break this down into multiple questions instead.

Comment: yes, I could do that, but I thought that would appear too spammy. and tbh I was expecting this to be a question more or less for the core devs, since they could pick an item from my unspecific question they're familiar with and feel like they can guesstimate on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Monero is run as an open source project, rather than a startup. As such, it is developed at the speed at which its contributors... contribute. Something getting done depends on someone with the right skills deciding to help, and finding the time to do so. As such, no timeline can be given. Funding does help, as some people will pour more time if funded, but that can hardly be made into a cost estimate.

About the specific items mentioned on the image you link to, there are a few things that are out of date:

- 0MQ isn't done. It was pretty much working months ago, but issues with it ended up with a rewrite being started.
- SSL/TLS does not exist. I understand this is something that comes with 0MQ.
- client side handling of unconfirmed transactions is done (<strike>waiting to be merged</strike> now merged, see https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/pull/916)
- address and tx signing, key export is mostly done - tx signing may not be, I'm not sure what this is, but the other two were merged in the last week or so